# Running a bash script inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

How can I start a script after running a docker container.

Here is a part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nodesource/trusty:0.10.30
RUN mkdir /opt/app/ && cd /opt/app/
ADD ./api/package.json /opt/app/package.json
RUN cd /opt/app/ && npm install
ADD ./api/src /opt/app/src
RUN npm -g install pm2
WORKDIR /opt/app/src
ADD start.sh start.sh
RUN chmod 755 /opt/app/src/start.sh
CMD ./opt/app/src/start.sh
```

and start.sh contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /opt/app/src
node app.js --env=dev:
pm2 updatePM2
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

PS: When I start the script after logging to the containerit works perfectly but not when calling it directly from Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

A path is not a valid argument to [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) . It should be:

```
CMD ["./opt/app/src/start.sh"]
```

Comment: A plain string with a path can be specified. It's the "shell" form

Answer (score 0):

You have set your `WORKDIR` to `/opt/app/src` then you are trying to run the script relative to that location by using `./`. This means you are trying to run `/opt/app/src/opt/app/src/start.sh`

Try

```
CMD /opt/app/src/start.sh
```